# Making an array of various columns in spotfire

Tags: analytics, spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and am working on an analysis. I have made four bar charts, but I want to integrate them all into one. I want to make an array of four different calculated columns, and then represent them all in one value axis. How would I go about doing this?

[image: These four charts i want to combine into one chart with 4 bars Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put all your columns on the value axis, then color by `(Column Names)`

as a custom expression, your value axis might look like:

```
Sum([Column1]) as [Sum of Column1],
Avg([Column1]) as [The Average],
Max([Column2]) as [Another Measure]
```

you can view this by right clicking on the value axis' axis selector (the little gray box with the dropdown) and choosing **Custom Expression**.

---

alternatively, you can use the trellis options (in the visualization's Properties dialog on the **Trellis** page) to achieve a slightly different effect. set the Trellis by to `(Column Names)` to get an idea of this.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively you can use property controls where you put your variables and let the user select the one he wants to view. This is helpful if the scale of the variables is quite different. And keeps the visualisation nice and neat. You can even let the users choose multiple variables if you want.

See for more information also this [quick reference topic](http://spotfire.tibco.com/qrt/J7LRA/presentation.html) on the [spotfire quick references website](http://spotfire.tibco.com/learn/quick-reference-topics)