# Displaying 4 custom expression in one graph

Tags: analytics, ironpython, spotfire

I need to use **PG_Fiscal Quarter(Date(2015,10,1))** to make quarter 1. Similarly by putting four other starting dates in the fiscal quater I need four quarters in one bar graph. How can i have that. i cant simply assign them in custom expression

Comment: define having 4 quarters in one bar chart. Next to each other, stacked? An example of how you would like it to look like would help. See also this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes....four bars next to each other.

Comment: how is this different from your previous question which has already two answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848484/making-an-array-of-various-columns-in-spotfire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @niko said, this is almost the same as your previous question. But basically you want show your data with 4 quarters in your bar chart.

In that case, do not make 4 variables, but make 1 date variable and let spotfire do the splitting in quarters. This is a standard functionality in spotfire to create date hierarchies.

On your category axis you can select the date and set this to quarters. Spotfire will then show all the quarters in your date. This also opens up the possibility to use the standard expression like year to date, difference, etc.

Comment: if i give one starting date and then let spotfire split into quarter it gives only one quarter ..i want 4 such quarter . so how do i put it in the custom expression